# play framework: why do I have to refresh twice to see the changes?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using play! 2.4.x and I have to refresh the page a few times to actually see the changes, sometimes up to 4 times.

I got the same results on chrome, Safari and Firefox, on Mac and Linux.

It's in development mode if that matters, I think it's some kind of caching?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a guess. After you did some changes to your code Play has to compile those files again. This can take time, a couple of seconds. Is it possible that you actually don't have to refresh the page and the changes would come anyway after you just waited a couple seconds?

Comment: @Kris, Good point, you are talking about the IntelliJ auto refresh plugin ? If so: I'm not using it. but maybe I should actually use it and then just wait for the automatic refresh instead of refreshing manually.

Comment: it's not "IntelliJ auto refresh plugin" play have this feature already in development mode

Comment: @AndriyKuba, I tested that, no changes, it does not refresh.

Comment: maybe you will add some more info about your project - is it large ? how many time it compile ? and so on. I heard that some people could have problem with hot redeploy because of some 3rd party libraries they use do some special things with their class loaders. I mean your question is very general - add some more info. For example I have ore then 10 small play projects both on scala and java - hot redeploy works perfect for me

Comment: @AndriyKuba, good to know, well this is an issue that is always present, no matter how big or small the project was, even some of those scaffolding projects from play.

Comment: maybe you have project sources on the network drives ?